# nginx visit flask's .sock permission denied in ubuntu16.04

Tags: sockets, ubuntu, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I build a project with flask, uwsgi and nginx in ubuntu16.04 as the [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) said, and get the exception 502 Bad Gateway.
I checked the log and found that the visit of .sock file has a permission denied

what the log said :

```
2018/07/24 12:38:24 [crit] 8805#8805: *1 connect() to unix:///home/mylegendarytime/final/final.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///home/mylegendarytime/final/final.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

and my nginx setting :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///home/mylegendarytime/final/final.sock;
    }
}
```

I don't know what error leads to this bug. I have tried

```
$ chmod 777 ~/final/final.sock
```

but nothing changed

Edit :

this is my uWSGI setting:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

master = true
processes = 5

socket = final.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

I tried to change chmod-socket to 777 but it's useless.

And this is my systemd unix file :

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve final
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mylegendarytime
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/mylegendarytime/final
Environment="PATH=/home/mylegendarytime/final/finalenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/mylegendarytime/final/finalenv/bin/uwsgi --ini final.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solve it by change the user as www-data, because the nginx use this name to use socket. You can check it at nginx.conf.